# Preload Link found for Google Adsense, but wasn't used by browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, adsense

My Wordpress-Website [*followmyinstagram.de*] runs Google Adsense implemented within the head tags and some text areas. The code is written directly into a Child-Theme so I am not using any plugins for Adsense.

By analysing the site's page speed Chrome throws out:

Warnings: A preload link was found for "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/show_ads_impl.js" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.

The browser wastes a lot of time requesting the document this way. There must be an opportunity to, as it says,  preload the link or to lazy-load the link after the site has been displayed. Thing is, the mentioned link does not occur anywhere in my site's code, so it must be fetched by the original link within the Adsense-block. How can I fix this error?

According to [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-am-getting-a-warning-in-during-google-page-speed-test/] some plugins may interfere with Adsense but I have already tested all of my 8 plugins.

Caching plugins that could be interfering: Autoptimize, WP Super Cache

The Error disappears of course, if I remove the Adsense-code-snippets.

## That's my header.php

```
<head>
    <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" ></script>
    <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-**************",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
    </script>

</head>
```

Warnings: A preload  was found for "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/show_ads_impl.js" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do nothing about it, This is a matter for Google to fix, But preloaded resources might be used in after render events.